# retrieve data from confused html mail using php

Tags: php, html, dom

I need to retrieve confused html from a mail. so I have done it before using the class but here is different...so I need the part in the table---td-div with the details about the module subsciber. but before this table you have others. here is the html:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<div>Nome: GIANCARLO</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div>Cognome: CANNONE</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div>Codice Fiscale: CNNGCR65T01A285W</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div>Email: <a href="mailto:giancarlocannone@hotmail.com">giancarlocannone@hotmail.com</a></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean in "confused"?

Comment: this is just the part with the data I need to retrieve, but there are lots of empty div and tables...

Comment: Not sure I understand, but take a look at [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) - This link show how to load HTML from a string (You can also load the html [from a file](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php)) - Then, you need to select the table using the [getElementsByTagName()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) function. You can also read this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_dom_parser_example.htm) about parsing an manipulating HTML with PHP

Comment: well I just need to retrieve the data you see here. I have used the dom html before with the xpath to retrieve the class. but here there is no class and I have many more tables around this mail...anyway I will have a look at these links, thanks.

Comment: In that case you need to use [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) And select the elements with the following path  `//table/tbody/tr/td/div`

Comment: ok I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: why is this not working...    $dom_m = new DomDocument();
            $dom_m->loadHtml($body);
            $xpath = new \DOMXpath($dom_m);
            $div_p = $xpath->query('//table/tbody/tr/td/div');
            $div_private = $div_p->nodeValue;

            foreach ($div_private as $div){  print_r.... but nothing shows   }